# How to include jdk into Maven compiled jar

Tags: java, maven, javafx, dependencies

I have a project with Maven and JavaFX (using intellij CE on windows 10). I am trying to make a self-executing JAR . I would like all the dependencies **including the JDK** to be included in my JAR so that if a user does not have Java installed on their computer, it works anyway. I have managed to pack all the dependencies except the jdk. Can someone tell me how to achieve that in Maven?

this is my POM :

```
module Appiculture {

    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.web;
    //requires javafx.swt;
    requires sqlite.jdbc;
    requires java.sql;
    requires jasperreports;

    opens com.base.controllers.views;
    opens com.base.models.structure;

    exports com.base.controllers.views;
    exports com.base.models;
    exports com.base;
    //exports com.base.views;


}
```

this is my module-info:

```
module Appiculture {

    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.web;
    //requires javafx.swt;
    requires sqlite.jdbc;
    requires java.sql;
    requires jasperreports;

    opens com.base.controllers.views;
    opens com.base.models.structure;

    exports com.base.controllers.views;
    exports com.base.models;
    exports com.base;
    //exports com.base.views;


}
```

and this is my git repository:
https://github.com/Osolemio44/Appiculture.git

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage

Comment: Thank you. It is a very interesting tutorial, although it is not exactly what I am looking for. I am interested in continuing to work with java 11 and Maven. What I need is a way for Maven to include the JDK and have my application look for that included dependency instead of forcing the user to install Java. It is the last piece that I am missing since everything else, it does well.

Comment: that is not how it works - you create a jar with maven and then use jpackage tool to create an executable for a specific platform

Comment: sorry. i dont understand why you say that is not how it works. Maven can package autoexecutable jar with the maven-jar-plugin, Maven Assembly Plugin or Maven Shade Plugin ( i followed this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) with all the dependencies the app need. The only thing i try is to also add the jdk.

Comment: this seems like what you are looking for https://github.com/wiverson/maven-jpackage-template

Comment: Thanks, but checking the url you just passed, they recommend to use JDK16. i am using jdk11LTS. By the way, i am not interested in making an exe or any nativie aplication . Just an autoexecutable jar file with the jdk included.

Comment: unless host has jre and/or maven installed that is not possible

Answer (score 2):

Mr Asgarov is right.

To execute a JAR, there has to be an installed Java. So it is not possible to have a JAR that includes a JDK and therefore runs without an installed Java.